# How to check if a function parameter is a string or array in Perl

Tags: function, perl, arguments, subroutine

I'm trying to write a custom `validateParameter` function with Perl.
I have the following code which also works:

```
sub validateParameter {
    my ($args, $list) = @_;
    
    if ( ref($list) eq "ARRAY" ) {

        foreach my $key (@$list) {
            if ( not defined $args->{$key} ) {
                die "no $key given!";
            }
        }
    } 
    #elsif ( check if string ) {
    #}
}
```

I want to call my function the following way:

```
validateParameter({ hallo => "Welt", test => "Blup"},  ["hallo", "test"]);
```

But I also want to call my function like this:

```
validateParameter({ hallo => "Welt", test => "Blup"},  "hallo");
```

I know that Perl only has the following three data-types (scalars, hashes, arrays). But maybe there is a smart way to check if a variable is a string.

How can I check if the given arg is a string?

Comment: Do you mean "string" as opposed to "number"? Or "string" as opposed to "arrayref/hashref/..."? Then [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) is the way to go (as you already did). It returns an empty string for simple non-ref scalars (like your `$list`).

Comment: Ohh okay my fault :D. This post is done. Thanks @PerlDuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to check if a scalar is a string, as Perl does implicit type conversions depending on context. If you give a number as the second argument to your function, and you use it in a context that requires a string, it will be automatically converted to a string. So, just check if ref($list) is empty - in such case, $list is not a reference, and therefore it is a string or a number, and you don't need to distinguish between those two.

Comment: Well, there is [Scalar::Util::looks_like_number](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#looks_like_number) (core module) to detect numbers, but I don't think that is what the OP was after.

Comment: Note that `ref($list)` will return true for objects that a stringification overload. That means that `my $url = URI->new('http://stackoverflow.com/'); validateParameter({ hallo => "Welt", test => "Blup"},  $url);` will fail if you use `ref ` even if `$url` can be used as a string.

Answer (score 5):

Update:  I somehow missed the end of the question.  Just testing `ref($list) eq 'ARRAY'` will work most of the time, but to properly allow even overloaded objects, you should just try dereferencing the parameter:

```
if ( eval { \@$list } ) {
    # it was an array 
}
else {
    # assume it is a string
}
```

Original answer:

You can check a number of things about a parameter:

```
if ( ! defined $param ) {
    # undefined
}
elsif ( defined Scalar::Util::blessed($param) ) {
    # object
}
elsif ( ref $param ) {
    # reference (return of ref will give the type)
}
elsif ( length do { no warnings "numeric"; $param & '' } ) {
    # number
}
else {
    # string
}
```

But all of that (except perhaps the defined check) kind of defeats the purpose of Perl's automatically converting to your desired type and will limit what can be passed (for instance, a string or dualvar where a number is wanted, or an overloaded object where a string, number, or reference is wanted, or tied variables or magic variables such as `$!`).

You may want to also just look at what [Params::Validate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Params::Validate) can do.

Comment: Note: `\@$list` will auto-vivify `$list` if it's `undef`, so handle `undef` first if that's a valid input.

Comment: @ikegami I was guessing that undef would be more like an empty array than an undef "string"

Answer (score 1):

Don't base behaviour on the "type" of arguments because there really isn't such a thing. You will run into problems if you use type-base polymorphism because Perl values often have more than one type.

For example,

- The scalar produced by `"123"` is stored as as string, but Perl doesn't distinguish it from the scalar produced by `123` which isn't stored as a string.
- Scalars can contain both a number and a cached stringification of that number. (e.g. `my $i = 123; "".$i;`)
- Scalars can contain both a number and a string (that isn't a stringification of the number). Common examples of these are `$!` and `!1`.
- A reference to an object that overloads stringification is also a useful string. (e.g. `DateTime->now`)
- A reference to an array may overload `%{}` to usable as a hash reference. A reference to an hash may overload `@{}` to usable as an array reference.
- And more.